# Promise.all strange resolution issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Consider these two functions when i call
getStatusAll(data)-

```
data=[[],['1'],['2'],['3']];

async function getStatusAll(data) {
    console.log("In getStatusAll");
  try{
    let statusPromiseArray =  data.map(async(value) => { 
      result= await this.fetchStatusDBs(value);
      return result;
    });
    statusResolvedArray= await Promise.all(statusPromiseArray)
    return statusResolvedArray;
  }catch(err){
    throw(err);
  }
}

async function fetchStatusDBs(data) {
    console.log("In fetchStatusDBs");
  try{
      //fetch status in dvf_req_id for an dvf_req_id
      if(data.length==0){
        console.log("1");
        dvfStatus = await Promise.resolve("Disabled");
        console.log("2");
        trainingStatus = await Promise.resolve("Disabled");
        console.log("3");
        inferenceStatus = await Promise.resolve("Disabled");
      }
      else {
        console.log("4");
        dvfStatus = await Promise.resolve("Enabled");
        console.log("5");
        trainingStatus = await Promise.resolve("Enabled");
        console.log("6");
        inferenceStatus = await Promise.resolve("Enabled");
      }
      return [dvfStatus,trainingStatus,inferenceStatus];
  }catch(err){
    throw(err);
  }
}
```

I am trying to resolve multiple Promises within a Promise.all
but the results is unexpected.
Actual Output-

```
In getStatusAll
In fetchStatusDBs
1
In fetchStatusDBs
4
In fetchStatusDBs
4
In fetchStatusDBs
4
2
5
5
5
3
6
6
6
[["Enabled","Enabled","Disabled"],["Enabled","Enabled","Enabled"],["Enabled","Enabled","Enabled"],["Enabled","Enabled","Enabled"]]
```

Expected Output-

```
In getStatusAll
inside map
In fetchStatusDBs
1
2
3
inside map
In fetchStatusDBs
4
5
6
inside map
In fetchStatusDBs
4
5
6
inside map
In fetchStatusDBs
4
5
6
[["Disabled","Disabled","Disabled"],["Enabled","Enabled","Enabled"],["Enabled","Enabled","Enabled"],["Enabled","Enabled","Enabled"]]
```

But changing fetchStatusDBs like this returns output in the correct format.

```
async function fetchStatusDBs(data) {
    console.log("In fetchStatusDBs");
  try{
      if(data.length==0){
        dvfStatus = "Disabled";
        trainingStatus = "Disabled";
        inferenceStatus = "Disabled";
      }
      else {
        dvfStatus = "Enabled";
        trainingStatus = "Enabled";
        inferenceStatus = "Enabled";
      }
      return [dvfStatus,trainingStatus,inferenceStatus];
  }catch(err){
    throw(err);
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: You don't declare `dvfStatus` and so on, so they are either "shared" within a single outer scope (if you declare them there), or implicitly global variables (if you fail to declare them anywhere - which btw is very bad practice). So as each Promise runs "concurrently" (not actually, but it's as well to think of it as if they do), the setting and reading of these variables overlaps with each other, in ways that aren't necessarily easy to predict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that the status variables in `fetchStatusDBs` are undeclared and therefore [implicitly global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Since your code is making multiple concurrent calls, which are interleaved at the `await` suspension points, they affect each other - a classic race condition. To fix this, just declare the variables with `let` or `var`.

```
const data=[[],['1'],['2'],['3']];

async function getStatusAll(data) {
    console.log("In getStatusAll");
    let statusPromiseArray = data.map(this.fetchStatusDBs, this);
    return Promise.all(statusPromiseArray);
}

async function fetchStatusDBs(data) {
    console.log("In fetchStatusDBs");
    let dvfStatus, trainingStatus, inferenceStatus;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //fetch status in dvf_req_id for an dvf_req_id
    if (data.length==0) {
        console.log("1");
        dvfStatus = await Promise.resolve("Disabled");
        console.log("2");
        trainingStatus = await Promise.resolve("Disabled");
        console.log("3");
        inferenceStatus = await Promise.resolve("Disabled");
    } else {
        console.log("4");
        dvfStatus = await Promise.resolve("Enabled");
        console.log("5");
        trainingStatus = await Promise.resolve("Enabled");
        console.log("6");
        inferenceStatus = await Promise.resolve("Enabled");
    }
    return [dvfStatus, trainingStatus, inferenceStatus];
}
```

This will have the desired results (return value). To also get the expected output from the logs, you cannot use `map` with an asynchronous function and then wait for all the promises with `Promise.all`, but you need to make the calls in sequence:

```
async function getStatusAll(data) {
    console.log("In getStatusAll");
    const statusArray = [];
    for (const value of data) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        statusArray.push(await this.fetchStatusDBs(value));
//                       ^^^^^
    }
    return statusArray ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several misunderstandings about async-await

```
async function getStatusAll(data) {
    console.log("In getStatusAll");
  try{
    let statusPromiseArray =  data.map(async(value) => { // map is sync
      result= await this.fetchStatusDBs(value); // global result
      return result; // return-await anti-pattern
    });
    statusResolvedArray= await Promise.all(statusPromiseArray) // global
    return statusResolvedArray; // return-await anti-pattern
  }catch(err){  // catch-throw anti-pattern
    throw(err);
  }
}
```

All of that can be written as -

```js
function getStatusAll(data) {
  return Promise.all(data.map(v => this.fetchStatusDBs(v)))
}
```

And any error will automatically bubble up. No need to `catch` and re-`throw`. This will do all the fetches in *parallel*. You could do the requests in *serial* if you wanted. This is shown to demonstrate proper use of `await` in `async` -

```js
async function getStatusAll(data) {
  const result = []
  for (const value of data)
    result.push(await this.fetchStatusDBs(value))
  return result
}
```

Comment: Got it but if i am using the result of await in code below it.
Then I should write try and catch right?

Comment: ```
async function getModelsSummary(orgId){
    var query="SELECT objective,uid,last_updated_time FROM `model_enabled_status` where org_id = ? and is_enabled='1'";
    console.log("In service getSummaryDetails");
    try{
        queryOutputList = await dObject.query(query,[orgId]);
        reqIDsList = await serviceHelper.getReqIDs(queryOutputList[0]);
        statusList = await serviceHelper.getStatusAll(reqIDsList);
        console.log("\n response Body:" + JSON.stringify(statusList));
        return statusList;
    }catch(err){
        throw(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: @UjjwalMadan No. You should only write `try { … }` if your `catch` block does something other than just rethrowing the error. (Notice this has nothing to do with async/await, it's the same for synchronous code).

Comment: That's right. If you ever see yourself writing `... catch(err) { throw error }` simply remove the entire `try`/`catch` block. Same goes for `return await someFunc()`, in an `async` function it is the same as `return someFunc()`