# Javascript nested asynchronous calls execution order

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I'm having trouble understanding how asynchronous code runs in javascript.

I have a code similar to the following:

```js
const start = name => console.log(`${name} started`);
const finish = name => console.log(`${name} finished`);
const wrap = async (promise, name) => {
    start(name);
    const promiseResult = await promise;
    finish(name);
    return promiseResult;
}
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const inner = async ms => {
    return await sleep(1000);
}
const outer = async ms => {
    await wrap(inner(ms), 'inner1');
    await wrap(inner(ms), 'inner2');
    await wrap(inner(ms), 'inner3');
}
const testPromise = async promise => {
    const t0 = performance.now();
    const promiseResult = await promise;
    const t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(`Running promise took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds`);
    return promiseResult;
}
testPromise(wrap(outer(5000), 'outer'));
```

The output of the above code is:

```
inner1 started
outer started
inner1 finished
inner2 started
inner2 finished
inner3 started
inner3 finished
outer finished
Running promise took 3026.2199999997392 milliseconds
```

As you can see in the output, `inner1` was started before `outer` started, which is very weird! What I expect is that all `inner` calls start and finish within the start and finish of `outer`.

I did a lot of research on Google but couldn't find anything helpful unfortunately.

What worked for me is to explicitly emulate `wrap` function for `outer` call like below:

```js
const start = name => console.log(`${name} started`);
const finish = name => console.log(`${name} finished`);
const wrap = async (promise, name) => {
    start(name);
    const promiseResult = await promise;
    finish(name);
    return promiseResult;
}
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const inner = async ms => {
    return await sleep(1000);
}
const outer = async ms => {
    await wrap(inner(ms), 'inner1');
    await wrap(inner(ms), 'inner2');
    await wrap(inner(ms), 'inner3');
}
const testPromise = async () => {
    const t0 = performance.now();
    const outerName = 'outer';                // -- emulate calling `await wrap(outer(5000), 'outer')`
    start(outerName);                         // --           
    const promiseResult = await outer(5000);  // --
    finish(outerName);                        // -- finished emulation of `wrap`
    const t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(`Running promise took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds`);
    return promiseResult;
}
testPromise();
```

The output of the above code is what I really expect:

```
outer started
inner1 started
inner1 finished
inner2 started
inner2 finished
inner3 started
inner3 finished
outer finished
Running promise took 3155.5249999510124 milliseconds
```

What am I doing wrong that makes `inner1` start before `outer` is started?

Comment: When you have `a(b())` the function call `b()` has to be resolved before `a()` can be processed. After all, you need the value from `b()` to pass to `a()`. Same thing happens with `testPromise(wrap(outer(5000), 'outer'));` - `outerr(5000)` has to be called *first*. Which in turn calls `inner`. Which logs it. There is a bunch of pausing and unpausing that happens afterwards which is why you get `outer` next.

Comment: The first thing you run is outer which immediately returns a promise. Then you run inner1 which also returns a promise and after 1000ms it resolves. This will run wrap for inner1, so the first output is inner1, because outer will take 5000ms to get to its wrap call

Comment: `const inner = async ms => { return await sleep(1000); }` is an anti-pattern. `const inner = () => sleep(1000)` does the *exact* same thing. In `outer` you write `await wrap(inner(ms), 'inner1');` but the `ms` argument is ignored. maybe you mean to write `await wrap(sleep(ms), "first")`? `wrap` returns a result but you didn't assign it to anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your question demonstrates a number of misunderstandings about the effective use of `async` and `await` -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

async function wrap (p, label) {
  console.log("started", label)
  const t = Date.now()
  const result = await p
  console.log("finished", label)
  return { result, delta: Date.now() - t }
}

async function inner () {
  await sleep(1000)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
}

async function outer () {
  const a = await wrap(inner(), "inner1")
  const b = await wrap(inner(), "inner2")
  const c = await wrap(inner(), "inner3")
  return [a, b, c]
}

wrap(outer(), "outer")
  .then(JSON.stringify)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
started inner1
started outer
finished inner1
started inner2
finished inner2
started inner3
finished inner3
finished outer
```

```js
{"result":[{"result":58,"delta":1004},{"result":58,"delta":1001},{"result":67,"delta":1000}],"delta":3009}
```

**async and await are not special**

It's a useful exercise to imagine that `async` and `await` do not exist and you have to invent them on your own -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

function* pick1 () {
  yield Await(sleep(1000))
  return Math.random()
}
  
function* pick3 () {
  const a = yield Await(pick1())
  console.log("first", a)

  const b = yield Await(pick1())
  console.log("second", b)

  const c = yield Await(pick1())
  console.log("third", c)

  return [a, b, c]
}

Async(pick3()).then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
first 0.22559836642959197
second 0.41608184867397835
third 0.3789851899519072
```

```js
[
  0.22559836642959197,
  0.41608184867397835,
  0.3789851899519072
]
```

Note the uppercase `Async` and `Await`. These are plain functions of our own making -

```js
const isGenerator = x =>
  x?.constructor == (function*(){}()).constructor

const Await = x =>
  isGenerator(x) ? Async(x) : Promise.resolve(x)

function Async (it) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    function next (x) {
      const {value, done} = it.next(x)
      return done
        ? resolve(value)
        : value.then(next, reject)
    }
    next()
  })
}
```

Hopefully this helps you see what's going on behind the scenes of `async` and `await`. It's nothing more than a bit of syntactic sugar to replace a program you could've written by yourself :D

Expand the snippet below to verify the behaviour of our homemade `Async` and `Await` below -

```js
const isGenerator = x =>
  x?.constructor == (function*(){}()).constructor

const Await = x =>
  isGenerator(x) ? Async(x) : Promise.resolve(x)

function Async (it) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    function next (x) {
      const {value, done} = it.next(x)
      return done
        ? resolve(value)
        : value.then(next, reject)
    }
    next()
  })
}

const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

function* pick1 () {
  yield Await(sleep(1000))
  return Math.random()
}
  
function* pick3 () {
  const a = yield Await(pick1())
  console.log("first", a)
  const b = yield Await(pick1())
  console.log("second", b)
  const c = yield Await(pick1())
  console.log("third", c)
  return [a, b, c]
}

Async(pick3()).then(console.log, console.error)
```

For more info on misuse of `async` and `await`, please see [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67342850/633183)

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I found that asynchronous functions run synchronously until they reach either await or return.

The behavior that is happening in the first code can be explained as the following:

As in any function call, function parameters are evaluated first and before evaluating the function itself, calling `wrap(outer(5000), 'outer')` will evaluate the `outer(5000)` function call first. While evaluating `outer` call, and especially the first line `wrap(inner(ms), 'inner1')`, the same thing will happen, `inner(ms)` will be evaluated first registering the first promise in these nested calls which will be wrapped by `wrap` function (which is the first call to `wrap` function), and since `wrap(inner(ms), 'inner1')` is the first asynchronous call (first `await` statement) in `outer` function, then it will be evaluated synchronously, after that all other `await` statements will register other promises that depend on the first promise `await(inner(ms) 'inner1')`, then the `outer` function will be wrapped by `wrap`. This is why `inner1` is started first, `outer` is started after, then everything else runs as expected.

The solution I found for this is to pass a callback that returns the promise to `wrap` function instead of passing the promise right away.

```js
const start = name => console.log(`${name} started`);
const finish = name => console.log(`${name} finished`);
const wrap = async (promiseCallback, name) => {
    start(name);
    const promiseResult = await promiseCallback();
    finish(name);
    return promiseResult;
}
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const inner = async ms => {
    return await sleep(1000);
}
const outer = async ms => {
    await wrap(() => inner(ms), 'inner1');
    await wrap(() => inner(ms), 'inner2');
    await wrap(() => inner(ms), 'inner3');
}
const testPromise = async promiseCallback => {
    const t0 = performance.now();
    const promiseResult = await promiseCallback();
    const t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(`Running promise took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds`);
    return promiseResult;
}
testPromise(() => wrap(() => outer(5000), 'outer'));
```

Comment: "*I found that asynchronous functions run synchronously until after the first await call in them.*" very minor correction: async functions run synchronously until they reach either `await` or `return`. At that point they immediately pause. When an `await` is reached, JS will start waiting for the value after it (it's a unary operator) to resolve. If you use `await` with a non-promise (e.g., `await 4`), it's going to behave as if it's `await Promise.resolve(4)`

Comment: Thank you for the correction and the help @VLAZ I edited my answer

Answer (score -3):

well from my understanding of asynchronous JS, all the code runs at the same time as opposed to synchronous code.

The only reason why that could be happening is that inner1 execution happens faster than outer.

Comment: Async doesn't mean concurrent. Async execution is still sequential in JS. Unless there are exceptions but this isn't any of those.

Comment: ok understood.  Thanks for the correction.  I am still a bit young to this.